# Conditionaly copy value from one row to another

Tags: sql, t-sql

I would like write select which copy value from one row to another row with condition - and this condition would by TRANSACTIONTYPE. 
Each row of each order id should have value from TRANSACTIONTYPE=1

My Example table

```
ID TRANSACTIONTYPE ORDERID VALUE
1   1              XXX     100
2   2              XXX     120
3   4              XXX     140
4   2              XXX     120
5   1              YYY     500
6   2              YYY     400
```

What i expect in select statment:

```
ID TRANSACTIONTYPE ORDERID VALUE
1   1              XXX     100
2   2              XXX     100
3   4              XXX     100
4   2              XXX     100
5   1              YYY     500
6   2              YYY     500
```

I have tried write same select statment for this but I failed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions:

```
select t.*,
       max(case when transactiontype = 1 then value end) over (partition by orderid) as new_value
from t;
```

If you are thinking about *updating* the value, then I would challenge the data model.  In that case, the value should probably be stored in the `orders` table, where `orderid` is defined.

Comment: Thanks a lot. 
Works perfectly